# Assigning a combo box as an input

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

The following codes written in netbeans is suppose to log each user belonging to the combo box into the system.ones the username,password and As  are matched, however am having issues in assigning the values in the combo box as a criterial for logging in

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)       

{
    String inputusername = jTextField1.getText();
    String inputpassword = jPasswordField1.getText();
    String inputAs = jComboBox2.getText();
    if(inputusername.trim().length() == 0 ||
            (inputpassword.trim().length() == 0) ||
            (inputAs.trim().length() == 0)) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Error.", "Incomplete Fields", 
 JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    }else{

        Login l = new Login(inputusername,inputpassword,inputAs);
        jTextField3.setText(l.Log());
```

Comment: Try using `JComboBox#getSelectedItem` instead.  You will need to cast the result to `String` as this method returns `Object`.

Comment: 1) `jComboBox2.getText();`  According to my JavaDocs, that would not compile.  Is this snippet from code that compiles without error?  2) *Don't ignore deprecation warnings!*  Vis. [`JPasswordField.getText()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPasswordField.html#getText%28%29) - ***Deprecated.** As of Java 2 platform v1.2, replaced by getPassword.*  -- At 1.7, it is time we should stop using methods deprecated (with *good* reason) in 1.2!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use:

`if (jComboBox.getSelectedItem.equals("name of one item in list")`

So if you had a jComboBox names planetsCombo that listed the planets, and you wanted to make criteria for Earth, it would say:

`if (planetscombo.getSelectedItem.equals("Earth")`

Hope I helped!

Comment: do you think you can alter the code with ur derived lines? i dont seem to be able to place if properly. thank you

Comment: Well it looks like for you it would be `String inputAs = jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();` 
if you wanted to find a certain item in the combo box, just treat each object as if it were a string